# Sort List<byte[]> from specific listindex till the end of the list in c#

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have been trying to do this from few days, but all i could do is sort the complete list but not able to sort from a specific index.

lets say i have the following list for example

```
List<byte[]> byteArrayList = new list<byte[]>();
byteArrayList.Add(new byte[]{1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 6, 7, 6, 45, 50, 39 });
byteArrayList.Add(new byte[]{0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99});
byteArrayList.Add(new byte[]{2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3 });
byteArrayList.Add(new byte[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 31, 21 });
byteArrayList.Add(new byte[]{1, 22, 32, 22, 3, 3, 3, 3, 12, 13, 14, 15 });
byteArrayList.Add(new byte[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 95, 85, 75});
```

and lets say the current list index

```
ListPoisition = 2;
```

Therefore the list should be sorted from ListPoisition == 2 till the end of the list.

The result list should look like:

```
byteArrayList = {  {1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 6, 7, 6, 45, 50, 39 },
                   {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99 },
                   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 31, 21 },
                   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 95, 85, 75},
                   {1, 22, 32, 22, 3, 3, 3, 3, 12, 13, 14, 15 },
                   {2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3 }
                };
```

This is just an example.But the actual list can contain N number of byte[].

Comment: You could leverage LINQ: `List.Take(2).Concat(List.Skip(2).OrderBy(...))`. You'd need to pass a custom `Comparer` to the `OrderBy` to compare two lists the way you want to.

Comment: And what code do you use for sorting? Without that information, it is not a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the custom comparer:

```
public class CompareByteArrays : IComparer<byte[]>
{
    public int Compare(byte[] a1, byte[] a2)
    {
        int shorterLength = a1.Length < a2.Length ? a1.Length : a2.Length;
        for(int i = 0; i < shorterLength; i++)
        {
            if(a1[i] < a2[i])
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else if(a1[i] > a2[i])
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        return a1.Length.CompareTo(a2.Length);
    }
}
```

And then this is the function to sort it from certain index:

```
public List<byte[]> SortFromIndex(List<byte[]> source, int index)
{
    return source.Take(index).Concat(source.Skip(index).OrderBy(o=>o, new CompareByteArrays())).ToList();
}
```

So this is how you would call in the main:

```
List<byte[]> byteArrayList = new List<byte[]>();
byteArrayList.Add(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 6, 7, 6, 45, 50, 39 });
byteArrayList.Add(new byte[] { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99 });
byteArrayList.Add(new byte[] { 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3 });
byteArrayList.Add(new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 31, 21 });
byteArrayList.Add(new byte[] { 1, 22, 32, 22, 3, 3, 3, 3, 12, 13, 14, 15 });
byteArrayList.Add(new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 95, 85, 75 });

List<byte[]> result = SortFromIndex(byteArrayList, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following extension method

```
public static void PartialSort<T>(this T[] array, int startIndex, int endIndex)  
{  
    T[] sortedList = new T[(endIndex - startIndex) + 1];  

    for (int i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++)  
    {  
        sortedList[i - startIndex] = array[i];  
    }  
    List<T> newList = new List<T>(sortedList);  
    newList.Sort();  
    sortedList = newList.ToArray();  

    for (int i = 0; i < sortedList.Length; i++)  
        array[i + startIndex] = sortedList[i];  
}
```

If you want to sort each array in the list from position 2, then you can do the following:

```
var start = 2;
foreach (var entry in byteArrayList)
{
    entry.PartialSort(start, entry.Length - 1);
}
```

here a working [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iay6cT)

If you want to sort each array from  the index 2 from the list, then you can do the following:

```
var ListPosition=2;
for (var index = 0; index < byteArrayList.Count; index++)
{
    if (index >= ListPosition)
        byteArrayList[index].PartialSort(0, byteArrayList[index].Length - 1);
}
```

Here a working [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qwlUpI)

**UPDATED**

Based on your the comments, you want to sort the list only and not the array inside, so here what you can do:

1. Define a custom comparer
2. Use the Sort method of the List

**The comparer class**

```
public class ByteArrayComparer : IComparer<byte[]>
{
    public int Compare(byte[] first, byte[] second)
    {
        // find the minimum length of the both arrays
        var length = first.Length > second.Length ? second.Length : first.Length;
        for (var index = 0; index < length; index++)
        {
             if (first[index] > second[index])
                  return 1;
             if (second[index] > first[index])
                  return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Your code should look like this

```
var ListPosition = 2;
if(ListPosition< byteArrayList.Count && ListPosition>-1)
     byteArrayList.Sort(start,byteArrayList.Count - start, new ByteArrayComparer());
```

Here a working [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lWgH6E)

Comment: you are sorting each element of each array of the list. I am trying to sort the list. (from position 2) ie: from byteArrayList[2] till byteArrayList[endOfList]. (not sorting the elements of each byte[]).  Please check my result byteArrayList.

Comment: for clarification , what is the result if the index of sorting was greater than on of the arrays in the list? it will be considered in the top of the sort?

Comment: and if 3 arrays on index = 2 they have same value let us say 3, which array  will come first? is there any criteria for that? to check the next index for example?

Comment: 1)  if(listPosition > byteArrayList.Count) // do nothing                                             2)  if 3 byte[] have same values. then no specific criteria. just ordering them one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
arrayList.Select(x => x.Take(2).Concat(x.Skip(2).OrderBy(y => y)).ToArray()).ToList();
```

If we go over it;

- `Select` first byte array and takes first 2 index. (because we will
  concat to sorted list)
- Then in `Concat`, we `skip` first 2 index and order it,
- After these, first two index and sorted rest binded to each other.

([`Skip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx)and [`Take`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.100).aspx)returns remaining elements, thats why [`Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx) used.)

Here is the [result](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EQdqpf)

Hope helps,

Comment: i am not trying to sort each element of byte[] from position 2. But what I am trying is to sort the list from ListPosition == 2. ie: from byteArrayList[2] till byteArrayList[endOfList] (without sorting each elements of the byte[])